# Extend stem pipe

Tags: valve, shutoff

This is picture of my under the sink shuttoff valve for sink supply line. I need to replace valve. I have few questions.

1) what kind of valve should I choose ? Sweat joint,compression or push to connect.

2) I will need to cut stem pipe first to remove oldvlave, that is going to reduce the length of it. I wonder what happens when I (or someone else)  need to replace valve  again after 30 years , after cutting valve, pipe won't be long enough for new valve.  Any way to extend pipe today so that I will have enough pipe length to replace valve next time ? You may say I should leave it to whoever is going to deal with that problem in future and not worry about that today, but I am just asking out of curiosity, Is there a better way ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a sweat-on valve, you should be able to remove it by heating with a torch until the solder is melted and then pull it off with a twisting motion with a pair a pliers.

Clean up the end of the pipe with some steel wool and/or sandpaper and re-sweat a new one in its place.  I would use a ball valve here instead of this style but either will do the job.

Should be no need to cut anything.